# Sorting And Merging Data Returned From Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm working on a web service using asp.net.
I'm creating a timetable display board like you see in airports, bus stations or train stations.
I am in charge of creating the services for 1 station, and there are other people in charge of the other stations.

I have created my web services and now im trying to consume the others.
I can consume them but everyone else has got their web services returning different values, for example, I'm returning route id, journey id, start location, end location, stops, days running, times. but other peoples web services may return data like route id, start, end, stops, times, platform, journey status. in one table, and the other data that matches up with mine in another web service.

So how do i filter out the data that i do not need, like platform and journey status in the example.
Also, how would I merge everyone's data from web services into 1 grid view so i can display all the trains that pass through my station.

I'm quite new to web services, but I am trying and I have got quite a bit done by myself, im just stuck on this bit.

I hope this isn't a stupid question

```
Dim allStations As New List(Of ScheduleEntry)

Dim ws1 As New Hull.ArrivaServices()
For Each u1 As Hull.Result In ws1.ShowRouteByStation("hrw")
    Dim s As New ScheduleEntry
    s.StartTime = u1.Departure
    s.StopTime = u1.Arrival
    allStations.Add(s)
Next

Dim ws2 As New Heathrow.Heathrow_Airport()
For Each u2 As Heathrow.Result In ws2.GetHeathrowTrains
    Dim s As New ScheduleEntry
    s.StartTime = u2.BeginTime
    s.StopTime = u2.EndTime
    allStations.Add(s)
Next

GridView1.DataSource = allStations
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: im really new to this. if their web service returns start, end, and stops. but I only want start and end, what can i do so the grid view dosent display stops. i cant edit their methods.

Comment: this is a bit of my code so far:
'Dim ws As New SERVICE.CLASS()
            GridView1.DataSource = ws.METHOD
            GridView1.DataBind()'

Comment: its returned through XML

Comment: When I hover over method it says: Public Function METHOD() As System.Data.DataSet

Comment: Hi again, Ive done what you said below. I have been working on it all day, trying different things but I cant get it. The problem is the SERVICE.Result bit. it says Type is not defined. Ive put my code above, its your code with the services and methods im using. really stuck on this

Comment: also, some services are returning datasets and some are returning datatables

Comment: All Sorted, Made huge progress today. Cheers John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the datasets to datatables to make it compatable with each other.

```
DatatableA.Merge(DatatableB)
```

So now DatatableA also Contains all the DatatableB collumns and rows.
If the column names are the same and the data type is the same, the 2 columns become 1.
So I made sure the data types were the same, if they werent I converted them, then renamed the column name in DatatableB to the column name in DatatableA.

```
DatatableA.Columns(columnnumber).ColumnName = "NewName"
```

Remember when counting the columnnumber, its left to right and the first column is 0

If I had to convert the datatype, I made a new column in DatatableB (Same name as corrisponding collumn in DatatableA)

```
DatatableB.Columns.Add("NewColumnName", GetType(DataType))
```

Then I created a loop to go through the datatable rows of the collumn with the data I want to convert

```
Dim i as integer
Dim z as integer
i = 0
    z = DatatableB.Rows.Count`
```

and putting the new converted data in the NewColumn by using

```
Do until i = z
DatatableB.Rows(i)("ColumnName") = "ConvertedData) 
Next
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't what we normally call sorting and merging, not really. The largest problem is that you have a number of services which all return similar data formats, but not identical. So your first step will be to make them identical: within your program.

First, decide what you want to display in your grid. Let's say you only want to display start and stop time. So make a class that can hold a start and stop time:

```
Public Class ScheduleEntry
    Public Property Start As DateTime
    Public Property Stop As DateTime
End Class
```

You will use a `List(Of ScheduleEntry)` to populate your grid.

Now, depending on which service you call, just take the Start and Stop and add them to your list. Assume the case of two services with different return values:

```
Dim allStations As New List(Of ScheduleEntry)

Dim ws1 As New SERVICE1.CLASS()
For Each u1 As SERVICE1.Result In ws1.METHOD
    Dim s As New ScheduleEntry
    s.StartTime = u1.Departure
    s.StopTime = u1.Arrival
    allStations.Add(s)
Next

Dim ws2 As New SERVICE2.CLASS()
For Each u2 As SERVICE2.Result In ws2.METHOD2
    Dim s As New ScheduleEntry
    s.StartTime = u2.BeginTime
    s.StopTime = u2.EndTime
    allStations.Add(s)
Next

GridView1.DataSource = allStations
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help John, I'll look into doing that now.